# Make the inner content of HTML Object be responsive

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place some html page inside an `object` tag using something like this:

```
  <div>
       <object data="page.html" style="width:100%;height:100vh;">
           <embed src="page.html" style="width:100%;height:100vh;"></embed>
       </object>
  </div>
```

The content shows right, but when I try to explore the page in responsive mode, the content withing the object tag keeps its proportion and everything looks narrow and awful (You need to make zoom to read for example).

What I want is that this content show its real size as it is responsive. I tried using few tricks with the `position` of `<div>` and `<object>` but none of them worked. Also I tried with Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/embed/ and still the same problem.

EDIT:
Some images to ilustrate the problem

What I see
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bCGD.jpg

What I need
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATJ1z.jpg

Comment: The included page `page.html` needs to have a responsive layout too, not only the main page. Just a quick hint: in `page.html` you can set style like this:
`<head><style> * { font-size: 5vh; } input[type="text"] {width: 80%;}</style></head>`
and it will be "more responsive". So first make the included document responsive and it will work.

Comment: @MichałDąbrowski The content is responsive as I said with "What I want is that this content show its real size as it is responsive". Also in the example shown in the pictures, the content was made using Bootstrap

Comment: If you provide full html + css code of `page.html` then i can help you. We are talking about responsiveness of content that is only known to you.

Comment: Here I placed the code of the inner HTML https://pastebin.com/yzTxUyXi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by adding the viewport to the parent container:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```